# Specific Heat (Differentiate or Divide by mass)

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I'd like to find the exact expression of specific heat (both real/ideal gas and liquid) for general purpose (CFD application) and I heard somewhere that you can just divide by the mass. So, my question is: Should I differentiate or divide by the mass for obtaining the specific heat formula?

$$ c=\frac{\partial C}{\partial m} $$
$$ c=E_m=\frac{C}{m} $$
$$C_p-C_v=T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V,n}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P,n}=-\frac{T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)^2_{V,n}}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_{P,n}}$$

Comment: For future reference, the word is "differentiate," not "derivate." Also, we request that you put your math in MathJax format so that it's readable by search engines: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: To obtain specific heat you should divide by mass, not differentiate.

Comment: Thanks @Deep for your response. However, I will need some proofs confirming that in order to be pretty sure.

Comment: It is the definition of specific heat. No proof can be given.

Comment: Problems could arise if the specific heat capacity is not constant.

Comment: @Farcher i think we need to use the differentiation formula in order to calculate the instantaneous specific heat per unit of mass basis. Like the same way when you'd like to the velocity of a particle.

Comment: If you are saying that, if you are dealing with a fluid in which the temperature is varying with spatial position, the local enthalpy *per unit mass* is equal to the heat capacity times a temperature difference, then you are correct.  And the enthalpy per unit volume is obtained by multiplying by the density (mass per unit volume).